# Move and left justificating y-axis label in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is my plot:

```
ggplot(iris,aes(Sepal.Length,Species, fill = Species)) + geom_col() +
            theme(axis.text.y = element_text(hjust = 0))
```

All I want is to move to the right the y-axis and justify them to the left to include them inside the bars.

When I change `hjus =` the labels are not left justified/aligned.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `geom_text()`:

```r
ggplot(iris,aes(Sepal.Length,Species, fill = Species)) +
 geom_col() +
 geom_text(aes(x = 100, label = Species))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your time! I got it. Just finishing using `hjust = 0`and its solved. Many thanks!